# Python: Merge two csv files and mark the unmatched both in master and using data

Tags: python, csv, merge

I am a bit new to python so sorry if my question is irrelevant. I have two csv files similar to this that I want to match

**file 1**

```
sa_name  
ABC  
DEF  
ACE  
ABCD  
BCD
```

And **file 2**

```
rs_name  
ABCD  
CDE  
DEFG  
ABCDE  
ABE
```

And I want my output file to be like this:
**output file**

```
sa_name, rs_name, merge  
ABC, ABCD, 3  
ABC, ABCDE, 3  
ACE, ,1  
DEF, DEFG, 3  
ABCD, ABCDE, 3  
ABCD, ABCD, 3
BCD, ABCD, 3  
BCD, ABCDE, 3  
 , CDE, 2  
 , ABE, 2
```

So the rule is that merge=3 if row in file1.csv is a substring of a row in file2, if the data is only in file1.csv then merge=1 and if the data is only in file2.csv then merge=2.

I only know how to get those rows with merge=3 but don't know how to merge two csv files and keep those unmatched in the output file and also indicate  whether they come from file 1 or file 2.
Here comes my code:

```
import csv

with open('file2.csv', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as RS:
RS_reader = csv.reader(RS)
rows = [row for row in RS_reader] 
print("RS data loaded...")

with open('file2.csv', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as SA:
with open('RS_SA.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as RS_SA:
    SA_reader = csv.reader(SA)
    print("SA data loaded")
    RS_SA_writer = csv.writer(RS_SA)
    RS_SA_writer.writerow(next(SA_reader, None) + rows[0])
    print("Header written to the ourput file...")

    d = 0
    for line in SA_reader:
        match2 = line[0]
        for row in rows:
            match1 = row[0]      
            if match2 in match1:
                new_row = [','.join(line+row)] 
                SA_writer.writerow(new_row)
                d = d+1
                print(d)
                print(new_row)
```

Anyone knows how to proceed?
Thanks a lot!

Some updates: in my file1 I have 100 columns and 6 millions observations and file 2 I have 20 columns with 3,500 observations. Those are not relevant for my matching so I didn't add them here in the example files.

Comment: I would read both files into a list, loop through both lists to construct a third list which you then write to a new csv

Comment: Can you use `pandas`? or are you limited to `csv` library?

Comment: @RickyKim Yes I can use pandas but my knowledge to pandas is more limited than to csv... But if it's more efficient I would like to switch :p

Comment: @PhillipWatts Can explain that more clearly? Do you mean I create the third list that contains both files?

Comment: Open file 1 and add each line to a list_1 -> [ABC, DEF, ACE...] then close file 1. Open file 2 and do the same so you end up with two lists (you can use pandas for this). Then loop through whichever list is longer. For each loop, you loop through the other list comparing the items and adding the result to a 3rd list. Then you write this 3rd list to CSV.

Comment: @PhillipWatts This is exactly what I am doing now, but I don't know how to add unmatched data both from file1 and file2 and mark them. It seems that it's not possible to realize the function by looping only once. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've read the two files into "sa_name" and "rs_name", this will give you a final_list which is a list of lists each one representing a row to write to a csv file. You can then sort by the first column if needed. This may need some validation depending on how big your file is etc

```
sa_name  = ['ABC','DEF','ACE','ABCD','BCD']
rs_name  = ['ABCD','CDE','DEFG','ABCDE','ABE']
found_rs_name, final_list = [], []

for sa in sa_name:
    found = False 
    for rs in rs_name:
        if sa in rs:
            final_list.append([sa,rs,3])
            found_rs_name.append(rs)
            found = True

    if not found:
        final_list.append([sa,"",1])

for rs in rs_name:
    if rs not in found_rs_name:
        final_list.append(["",rs,2])
```

Comment: Yes actually in my file1 I have 100 columns and 6 millions observations and file 2 I have 20 columns with 3,500 observations. So it's not easy to use a list. But I think I get your logic! I will try your method now :p

Comment: Following the logic of your code, now my code works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!